# Count number of sentences ending with puncutation mark in a textfile

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to make a function that counts the number of sentences in a textfile. In this case, a sentence refers to any string ending with either a '.', '?', or a '!'.

I'm new to Python and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this. I keep getting the error 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'numberofSentences' referenced before assignment.' Any help would be appreciated!

```
def countSentences(filename):
    endofSentence =['.', '!', '?']
    for sentence in filename:
        for fullStops in endofSentence:
            if numberofSentences.find(fullStops) == true:
                numberofSentences = numberofSentences+1
    return numberofSentences
print(countSentences('paragraph.txt'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the variable to something before incrementing it.  You also need to open the file itself,  read *it's* text and evaluate it - and not count what letters are in the given `filename`.

```
# create file
with open("paragraph.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("""
Some text. More text. Even
more text? No, dont need more of that! 
Nevermore.""")


def countSentences(filename):
    """Count the number of !.? in a file. Return it."""
    numberofSentences = 0      # init variable here before using it
    with open(filename) as f:  # read file
        for line in f:         # process line wise , each line char wise
            for char in line:
                if char in {'.', '!', '?'}:
                    numberofSentences += 1
    return numberofSentences

print(countSentences('paragraph.txt'))
```

Output:

```
5
```

Doku:

- [reading files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Answer (score 0):

It would work if you actually checked that the fullStop was in the sentence in the first place and you declared `numberOfSentences` beforehand.
The best method to do this I think would be to instead of using find, which returns a number, not a bool, would be to write

```
if sentence in endofSentence:  
    numberOfSentences+=1
```